# every 10 minute cron job behavior on two task with 8 hours interval

Tags: php, laravel, cron, laravel-scheduler

I am using Laravel schedule task and I have two cron jobs:

> One has to run at 00:10
>
> And another one at 08:00

I wanted to know if I set my cron job to this:

> */10 * * * * php .../artisan schedule:run

will this run my jobs? what if this cron job run at these times: 01:05, 01:15, 01:25,... will this run my job at 00:10 if it passes from that time?

And what else could be the best cron job for this situation?

Comment: You should use

" * * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1 "

as mentioned in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#introduction) . That will not miss any job either it is in 8 hrs interval or at 00:10.

Comment: @nitin7805 Thanks I know that this is offered by documentation to do this every minute but I don't want to do that I have a shared hosting on this website.

Comment: Questions that ask _"Give me a cron-schedule expression that runs a job at X"_ with no attempt are off-topic on Stack Overflow. Cron-schedule expressions are very well explained on the plethora manuals available such as [`man 5 crontab`](//linux.die.net/man/5/crontab), [The Cron wiki-page](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), [The SO cron-info page](//stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info) and most importantly [Why is my crontab not working, and how can I troubleshoot it?](//serverfault.com/questions/449651). Tools that can help you out are http://crontab.guru and http://www.cronmaker.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*/10 * * * * php .../artisan schedule:run 
// this will run every 10 minutes: 01:00, 01:10, 01:20
```

So it's stil workable for your current scenario.

However, if you have another job at 00:05, then you have to change the cron again, which is not advisable. Why not you just use `* * * * * php .../artisan schedule:run` ?

From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#introduction).

> This Cron will call the Laravel command scheduler every minute. When the schedule:run command is executed, Laravel will evaluate your scheduled tasks and runs the tasks that are due.

Comment: Thanks, Because I have a shared hosting for this website.

Answer (score 0):

You need to only run one cron for laravel schedule task. What you need to change is set time for that schedule task. Please refer https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling. This has much better explanation on schedule task in laravel.

Comment: Thank you, I know that but I don't want to have a cron job for every minute because lack of resources I have a shared hosting for this website